# How to fill landing card for UK for back-to-back entries and exits?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, multiple-entry

My trip to UK will include three short visits of duration 4days, 7days and 2days each with a gap of four days in between each visit. I will be visiting Europe from UK during those two gaps of 4days. I have the following question to ask:

1. What should I write on landing card regarding my "Length of stay in UK"?

a. Should I write 4days at the time of first entry, 7days at second time and 2days at third time?

or

b. Should I write 13days (4+7+2) at the time of first entry, 9days (7+2) at second time and 2days at third time?

or

c. Should I write 21days (4+4+7+4+2) at the time of first entry, 13days (7+4+2) at second time and 2days at third time?

In my opinion, the option (b) seems to be correct.

Comment: I think (a) is actually correct, but if you want to be overly cautious about avoiding any appearance of attempted deception, you can explain yourself to the immigration officer at your first entry, saying, "I'm not sure whether I answered this correctly, because I am planning to enter the UK two more times in the next three weeks, and I wasn't sure whether to include those visits in the total."

Answer (score 8):

There's no option to "reuse" the landing card because you surrender it at the passport control. So no matter what you wrote there - 13 or 21, on your second entry you will have to fill up a different landing card, even if you only stayed 4 days.

Thus every time you enter UK you fill up a new landing card, and specify the new duration. Duration is the period until you leave the UK. Thus you will write 4 days on the time of first entry, then 7 days, then 2 days and so on.

Comment: I was just in the same situation and, for what’s it worth, I was instructed by the person managing the line to put down the full amount on first entry. I actually counted all of the days from first entry to last exit, including the Europe days outside the the UK (total 21 days). I had no issues and received a new passport stamp each time.

Comment: @ DoxyLover, It means you entered the number of days for your subsequent visits by reducing the number of days (out of 21) you already spent in UK and Europe. Am I right?